# Current draw of a bilge motor

Tags: motor, amperage, coil

What happens at the coil when an electric bilge motor is stuck and stopped from spinning and the current draw increases beyond the rating (from 2 A to 8 A)?

Comment: it will probably overheat. Whether or not it has protection against that: nobody can know.

Comment: It would be advisable for the motor to have some current-sensing or temperature-sensing protection. The statement of the current change and the fact that will likely cause a destructive temperature increase pretty much define the results to be expected for any type of motor. Additional  details like the stalled torque and the time to failure depend on the specific motor design. With so few details, not much can be said.

Comment: If it is rated as a 2A motor, then place a 2A slow-blow fuse in line with it.  When the fuse blows, the motor was stuck.  Can sense voltage across the fuse to determine electrically if the fuse has failed (and sound an alarm or something.)

Comment: The manufacturer can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

A stalled Bilge pump will draw high current. In time the motor will burn out. A magnetic circuit breaker will be satisfactory because it can be manually reset at sea. This works for me on my jetboat. You could use a PTC to save the motor also. I have implemented a rotation sensor combined with a level sensor for an associate, this was more expensive but worked well in a flooding basement. This basement stuff was done 28 years ago when there was not so much off the shelf equipment. Nowdays you may be able to buy easier with doctor google.